# Deserialization case class from ByteString

Tags: scala, serialization, akka, akka-io

I send case class using:

```
tcpActor ! Tcp.Write(MyCaseClass(arg1: Class1, arg2: Class2).data)
```

Then I received:

```
case Tcp.Receive(data: ByteString)
```

Is there any simple way to match data on MyCaseClass without using low level java serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:
1. Use Akka remoting to send the case classes directly
2. Use Java serialization
3. Use https://github.com/scala/pickling
4. Write your own message protocol to convert between case classes and byte strings

Choose what best fits your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if akka provides any facility for de-serialising binary data, I didn't find any so far. A good option would be to use [scodec](https://github.com/scodec/scodec), which seems pretty good and quite popular in the scala ecosystem. By the way, where is that `.data` method you are using to serialise defined?